# Jupyter notebook is not opening

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, root-framework

I have installed anaconda package and my pc has already one package installed "root(data analysis package)".
So after installing anaconda I wanted to open jupyter notebook so I type "jupyter-notebook" in the terminal but somehow I am getting following error.

Could you please provide me a solution for this? Thanks.

the error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2143, in initialize
    super().initialize(argv)
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 239, in initialize
    self.migrate_config()
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 165, in migrate_config
    migrate()
  File "/home/souvik/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/migrate.py", line 245, in migrate
    with open(os.path.join(env['jupyter_config'], 'migrated'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/root/6.26.10-install/etc/notebook/migrated'*
```

I could not find any solution in google for this.

Answer (score 0):

After a glimpse at the error Message,
You seem not to have access to `/opt/root/6.26.10-install/etc/notebook/migrated`
How did you install the anaconda? (globally or on root?)

since you are currently running as user "souvik"
Try running:

```
sudo jupyter-notebook --allow-root
```

Then post back the results.

In case the above command started jupypter-notebook successfully,
we can change the ownership of `/opt/root/6.26.10-install/etc/notebook/`from `root`to you (souvik) using `chown`.

Comment: I tried sudo jupyter-notebook --allow-root but I am getting following error. sudo: jupyter-notebook: command not found

Comment: I followed this to install anaconda: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: what's your output for:  
`ls -l /opt/root/6.26.10-install/etc/notebook/`

Comment: four directories(custom, html, JsMVA, kernels) and one file jupyter_notebook_config.py.

Comment: I'm asking for the output to see the file owners and groups.
hence the `ls -l` command

Comment: opps! File owner and group are "root".

Comment: Feel Free to `sudo chown -R souvik:souvik /opt/root/6.26.10-install/etc/notebook/`  in case You're the main user of the PC/Machine/Notebook.